# HTML5 Local storage cannot find variable even though console.log reveals it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am using a sample script to populate a table in my website. Basically I want to copy save a persons answers persistently so if they refresh the page, their choices are still there. I have the function adding items to the table, the clear all button works, the main problem is the delete button will not work. I get the error; "can't find variable" in console, even though I can see the variable stored by checking `console.log(window.localStorage);`

```
window.addEventListener("load",updateTable,false);

function updateTable() {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("output");
    while (tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr").length > 0) {
    tbody.deleteRow(0);
    }
    var row;
    if (localStorage.length==0) {
        row = tbody.insertRow(i);
        cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.colSpan="4";
        cell.innerHTML = "Nothing to Show";
    }
    for (var i=0; i < localStorage.length; ++i) {
        row = tbody.insertRow(i);
        cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = i;
        cell = row.insertCell(1);
        cell.innerHTML = localStorage.key(i)
        cell = row.insertCell(2);
        cell.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
        cell = row.insertCell(3);
        cell.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteItem('+localStorage.key(i)+');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>';
    }
}
function deleteItem(key) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")) return;
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    updateTable();
}

function clearStorage() {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all local storage for this domain?"))     return;
    localStorage.clear();
    updateTable();
}

function save() {
    var key = document.getElementById("key").value;
    var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
    localStorage.setItem(key,value);
    updateTable();
}
```

Comment: Well, `console.log(window.localStorage)` will indicate that `window.localstorage` is an object. If you put a breakpoint in `deleteItem`, try outputting `localStorage.getItem('SOMEKEY')` and see if you get a value.

Comment: When I put that in I get "test" back test being the variable and key i inserted into table, and as well the table is populated with test and test in the key value area, it just can't seem to find it to delete it. Am I missing something in the on click call

Comment: Just as an aside, you might consider using `createElement()` instead of insertCell. According to this test framework, insertCell is a LOT slower, which means a potential bottleneck for you in the future if you have really extensive tables... http://jsperf.com/insertcell-vs-create-new-td

Comment: (Ok, the /only/ exception is that IE is faster with insertCell than createElement... nevertheless, for usable browsers, there is a noticeable performance difference...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not delimited the key in the delete call...

```
cell.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteItem(\''+localStorage.key(i)+'\');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>';
```

Notice I added the quotes around the key.  Try that and see if it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, thought it had to be something simple. It was look for deleteItem(test); and it should have been looking for deleteItem('test');

Comment: Sometimes the simplest things are the ones that we miss!  Glad I could help :)

Comment: I was using this as proof of concept to save data. Is there a way to save a table row and reproduce that in a second table. Essentially i have a table that has 3 columns in it and I can only pass two values to the new table. So column one is a picture, column two a lat and long, and column three the address. Right now I can pass the lat/long and address, I need to add the image

Comment: You could just get the whole row and save that in localStorage... `$("#tableID tr")[0].outerHTML` (for example)